# Failure to build ACE

Tags: make, openssl

I gunzipped and tarred `ace_tao5.6.3.tar.gz`. After creating the "ACE_wrappers" directory I successfuly ran `configure`. When I tried to **make**, I got an "Open SSL" missing dependency.

After installing the ubuntu open-ssl package using apt-get, I tried to **make** again, but it failed with errors such as:

```
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp: In constructor ‘getapp::getapp(int, char**)’:
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:92: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:107: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp: In static member function ‘static void getapp::usage()’: 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:142: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:147: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp: In member function ‘int getapp::run()’: 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:156: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:167: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope 
../../../../ASNMP/examples/get/get.cpp:181: error: ‘endl’ was not declared in this scope
```

I don't know how to proceed. Please advise me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After upgrading to ace_tao5.6.5.tar.gz, I configured and built **ace** sucessfully.

As I was trying to build **tao**, I realized that I already had a **.deb** for ace+tao! A **.deb** is a debian library that Ubuntu's operating system uses. I just ran **dpkg** on the .deb, and had ace+tao installed!